# Asp.net web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am a newbie and have just learned the basics of HTML, CSS, JS, C#, ASP.Net and now want to build a web app. Please refer me to a solution/project that I can follow to make my first web app with ASP.Net MVC. Your recommendations will be highly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

[Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: Thank you James. I thought it was link to instructional videos as it has same name as this link (which I already gone through). I saw its a project tutorial. Duh-uh of me..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer some Youtube tutorials. I like the below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pzwRwYlXMw&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net official website is better at beginning for learning MVC

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have gone through and learned Getting Started with MVC 5 on MSDN and I am also familiar with EF 6 and now looking to start my first web app project. Do you know of any sample project I can follow along?